# Rendering a response from a URL to RSS format

Tags: url, rss, controller

I am creating a controller that receives certain parameters from an application, then accesses a hard coded URL. Upon receiving a response from the URL my controller should render this response to RSS format.

In doing this I decided to use XPath to sort of create the xml tags, I then used StringBuilder to append these tags and then rendered the result as text. This is able to show on the browser just how I want it.

However when I try to view the page source it does not show any tags or headers, it just shows it as normal text on a page. I need help with  what to do so that the headers and tags can appear in the page source.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having your controller send the data as JSON, and then creating a template that renders the JSON as rss2/xml. For best results, make your JSON structure easy to loop over to create the RSS feed by looking at how feeds are organized.

Here's the [rss2 spec](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html)

make sure that this line is at the top of your file with NO leading spaces

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Also make sure your content is served with "text/xml" as its content-type. In php, one would set this as such:

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
```

See http://www.electrictoolbox.com/rss-php-content-type/

Comment: Hi Kasapo, I am a little bit confused as to what exactly to do. Could you please be more specific? Maybe a sample code could help. Thanks

Comment: Questions: What sort of response are you receiving from the hardcoded URL? Is it HTML content or are you receiving JSON data or is it an RSS feed? I assume your application sends POST data to the URL as well? Also, are you using a specific framework? If your XML is showing up as text, my first thought is the content-type header is set wrong. If you do "curl -I http://your.test.site/controller", you should see "text/plain" or "application/xml+rss" or something. If it's text/plain, then it'll show as text. If you can set the content-type header in your controller, that might help.

Comment: Also, google chrome will show the XML as raw text (text/plain) a lot of the time (either that or as XML), but FireFox will respect the content-type and show the rss as a feed. Try this one as an example: http://online.wsj.com/xml/rss/3_8068.xml Anyway, I can give you more specific examples if you let me know what language/framework you're using.